# How do I identify & fix a defunct MBR entry on a remotely-admin'd Win2008 Server?

Tags: windows, remote-access, mbr, bcdedit

My 1&1 Winserver had a disk replaced, and I managed to rebuild the RAID so I have once again two synched disks. The trouble is whenever the server is rebooted it seems to be still trying to boot from the defunct disk and hangs.
Most explanations on how to fix the MBR begin "Insert the installation disk..." – Not gonna happen.
I need guidance on how to fix this remotely. 1&1 obviously not interested.
Here's the o/p from BCDEDIT:

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  unknown
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {default}
resumeobject            {40e7e1d6-b2f2-11e1-928d-001999611846}
displayorder            {default}
                        {current}
                        {40e7e1e7-b2f2-11e1-928d-001999611846}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {default}
device                  unknown
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows Server 2008 R2
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {40e7e1d8-b2f2-11e1-928d-001999611846}
recoveryenabled         Yes
osdevice                unknown
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {40e7e1d6-b2f2-11e1-928d-001999611846}
nx                      OptOut
ems                     Yes

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows Server 2008 R2 - secondary plex
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {40e7e1d8-b2f2-11e1-928d-001999611846}
recoveryenabled         Yes
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {40e7e1d6-b2f2-11e1-928d-001999611846}
nx                      OptOut
ems                     Yes

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {40e7e1e7-b2f2-11e1-928d-001999611846}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows Server 2008 R2 - secondary plex - secondary plex

locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {40e7e1d8-b2f2-11e1-928d-001999611846}
recoveryenabled         Yes
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {40e7e1d6-b2f2-11e1-928d-001999611846}
nx                      OptOut
ems                     Yes
```

I just need to know how to remove the defunct entry and be sure to identify which one is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open an administrative command prompt and run these commands in order:

`bcdedit /deletevalue {default}`

`bcdedit /default {current}`

This:

- Deletes the `{default}` value
- Sets `{current}` as the default for `bootmgr` to load

Comment: Many thanks, that did the trick. Just needed a little hand-holding 8^) Cheers.

Comment: @Phaethon no worries! as long as it works :)